# Apple's Developer Certificate and Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, certificate

Can I use someone else's Apple's Developer Certificate and Provisioning Profile to build and run my application on the iPad ? Are the certificates and profiles Machine Specific ?

Actually I am trying to install my friend's dev certificate and it is getting installed but when I am installing the provisioning profile its showing me an yellow warning "[image: Warning in XCode Organizer]

The main question is that The Developer' Certificate and Provisioning profile can be used on different machines or not ?

Comment: "Can I use someone else's Apple's Developer Certificate and Provisioning Profile" No.

Comment: Thanks for quick response BoltClock. One more thing - Can I use my certificates and Provisioning Profiles on any new mac machine ?

Comment: You can use your own certificates on any machine you want, but you are not allowed to use the certificate of someone else.

Comment: ^^But it's showing me the same error.

Comment: I don't think it is a crime to experiment something(I am just using my friend's certificate and profile.) just for knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Error: "A valid signing identity
>   matching this profile could not be
>   found in your keychain"
>
> Solution: Most likely that you have
>   not downloaded the necessary WWDR
>   certificate from the Apple developer
>   site. There is a link to download this
>   certificate in the 'Certificates'
>   section of the developer portal. If
>   you do have the certificate in your
>   keychain, make sure that it has not
>   expired (unlikely, as mine is valid
>   until 2016). Also make sure that your
>   developer certificate has not expired
>   (these seem to be valid for only 12
>   months at a time)."

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2220082&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

See the message, "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found". You are adding the certificate in your keychain, not the identity(which is a .p12 file containing the private key). From wherever you got the certificate, you should get the private key exported from the keychain rather than exporting only the certificate.

At the end, like BoltClock said, it is violation of Apple's license to use some others' certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app on a device then you have to add that device's id to the certificate.

Comment: This is a partial answer; you also need to have the certificates installed on the computer, which is what the original question is about.